# Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, dependencies, clr

I tried to create a .NET console application that uses Windows Forms in order to create and save screenshots.
When creating a new console application project, I try to import the `System.Windows.Forms` library via the dependencies using a COM refernce.

After the import, I get the following error message in Visual Studio 2019:

`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Warning MSB3290 Failed to create the wrapper assembly for type library "{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}". Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly.  screenshot_console  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   2705`

The dependencies window looks like this:
[VS dependencies window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Uib.png)

I tried reinstalling VS and the .NET framework, but it did not resolve the issue.

Is there any way I can successfully import the library or is it not possible to import windows forms libaries to console applications?

Comment: You're using .Net Core, not .Net Framework. What .Net Core version? -- Add a Reference to the System.Windows.Forms assembly in a .Net framework Console app..

Comment: Take a console project.  The on menu use : Project : Add New Item : Window Form.  Put form code in the form.  Then create and instance on console of form : Form1 form1 = new Form1();  Then use form1.Show();

Comment: Sometimes using a COM component doesn't make sense. Try to add a reference to the assembly that implements it.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late response, got busy with some other projects in the meantime.

[@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) was right, I accidentaly created a .NET core project, therefore some references where not there and messed up the whole project.

Afterwards I was able to add the Windows.System.Forms reference without any issues.

Thank you for your help.